CPVC joint leaked and stopped - should I replace?
I ran a 3/4 CPVC water pipe. I used Oatey Medium Orange CPVC cement. This one particular joint must have had a good hour and a half to cure.  When I turned the water back on, it started leaking very slowly. I could also hear a rustling sound coming from around this area. I kept an eye on it for about 20 minutes. Nothing changed, it did not burst open. I then had to leave the house for about 3 hours. I came back, rushed to the pipe. There was a small drop sitting at the joint. I wiped it off and that's it! No more leaking. There is no puddle under that joint, so nothing has leaked for a while and whatever leaked must have been very minimal as there is no sign of it. I rocked the pipe as hard as possible without causing damage. No leaking. Should I cut and replace? Or should I wait and watch and see what happens? And if nothing happens, how long should I watch it for?

The set time on Oatey Medium Orange is between 1 minute to 5 minutes from 90 to 30 degrees F, according to Oatey's specification sheet.
You let the joint set for an hour and a half, which is well beyond the cement's set time.
So whatever stopped the leak wasn't the cement. It could have been sediment or temperature-based expansion/contraction.
This leak will rise again.
If water leaking here will be a problem. I would replace the leaking joint.

Thank you. It is actually leaking, but super slow.  I will be replacing it the first moment I get.
